# How to embed a multiple subplots inside another subfigure using grouplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, tabularx, groupplots

Could somebody please give me a hint of how can I do this using grouplots and tikz. I have done it using subfigure and \includegraphics, however, I am facing problems to arrange the borders of the plots relatively to the other plots.

[image]

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./Figures/c11.tex}
    \caption{}
\end{subfigure} \quad
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./Figures/c22.tex}       
    \caption{}
\end{subfigure} \\
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./Figures/c33.tex}
    \caption{}
\end{subfigure}\quad
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}
        \includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{./Figures/c44-1.tex}  \quad
        \includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{./Figures/c44-2.tex}\\[-3pt]
        \includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{./Figures/c44-3.tex}  \quad
        \includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{./Figures/c44-4.tex} \\[-3pt]
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{bla bla}
\label{Figure1} 
\end{figure}
```

When I use this code, I get the following Figure. I want it to be perfectly aligned.

[image]

I tried to use groupplots but I am not sure how to set the subfigure that is built with 4 subplots. This is a MWE.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}    
\begin{figure}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{groupplot}[
             group style={group size=2 by 2},
             cycle multiindex* list = {very thick\nextlist red\nextlist only 
             marks\nextlist}
       ] 
       \nextgroupplot \addplot {x}; \addplot {x^2};
       \nextgroupplot[cycle list = {red, blue}] \addplot {x}; \addplot {x^2};
       \nextgroupplot \addplot[green] {x}; \addplot {x^2};
       \nextgrouplot %Here I am not sure what to do
                \begin{groupplot}[
                                group style={group size=2 by 2},
                                cycle multiindex* list = {very 
                                thick\nextlist red\nextlist only 
                                marks\nextlist}
                                ]
                \nextgroupplot \addplot {x}; \addplot {x^2};
                \nextgroupplot \addplot {x}; \addplot {x^2};
                \nextgroupplot \addplot {x}; \addplot {x^2};
                \nextgroupplot \addplot {x}; \addplot {x^2};
            \end{groupplot}
      \end{groupplot}
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide us with an MWE that shows what you have tried. (Or do you expect us to make up a group plot from scratch?)

Comment: @marmot, I did a modification of the question, I hope it can give you an idea of what I am looking for. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks for improving your question! However, usually we post minimal working examples, which start with `\documentclass`, end with `\end{document}` and can be compiled. Even if I added the preamble to your code, I would not be able to run it because of `\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{./Figures/c44-1.tex}` and the like. Apart from the fact that I do not have `c44-1.tex`, one cannot include TeX files via `\includegraphics`.

Comment: Thank you, I can put all the code, but it is long. So, what I am looking for is a hint of how can I use groupplot inside \nextgroupplot. I do not want you to solve it, just an idea.

Comment: @marmot, I have updated the question again. I put a MWE to explain what I am looking for. Thank you

Comment: Any answer @marmot?

Comment: You still have things like ` \includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{./Figures/c44-1.tex}` in your code.

Comment: That's fine with me but then please do not ping me. If you want me to look at your problem, consider removing the errors from your example. If you feel that this is too much to ask, I respect this but would kindly like to ask you not to ping me.

Comment: Just to know, Did you see the MWE that you asked me to put?